# iOS Facebook SDK : gender being localized

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbsdk

I need to retrieve the gender of a user logged via the Facebook SDK.

Everything works but the Facebook Graph API sends me the gender information with a localized string.
For english, it's "male" or "female", so I can parse, but for other countries, depending on the locale of the user, it gives me translated string ("homme" for french, "ekrek" for turkish, ...).

I'm working on a app opened in 20+ countries, and opening countries each month, so I can't take care of a list of translated values.

On other platforms, developers have the ability of setting the locale manually (locale = en_US) in the Graph API request, but on iOS, the locale is overriden after, inside the SDK : (FBSDKGraphRequestConnection.m, line 471)

```
request.parameters[@"locale"] = [NSLocale currentLocale].localeIdentifier;
```

Does anyone with the same problem have found a solution to retrieve the gender in a consistent way ?

I'm using the 4.8 version of the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed in Facebook v4.10.0[1] released on February 10, 2016

- Fixed bug that would overwrite explicit "locale" parameters on graph requests.

[1] https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/change-log-4.x